# Make NetBeans build for two architectures

Tags: c++, netbeans, x86, x86-64

I have a C++ project and NetBeans is build it for x86 by default (even I'm on a x64 machine). I know I can change the project's settings and make NetBeans build the project for x64 by default, but I'm wondering if I can make NetBeans, somehow, build the project for both x86 and x64.

Any idea how could that be done?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating 4 different profiles for building. 2 for debug (x86 and x64) and 2 for release (x86 and x64). Then I run make like this:

```
make CONF=Debug_x86  (or Debug_x64, Release_x86, Release_x64)
```

This is, unlesss I have missed something, the closest way to get what I'm asking.